# GTM is not triggering for DOMReady Events

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to pass utm parameters to the other pages. I followed this article: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/transfer-utm-parameters-google-tag-manager/

I created this trigger in GTM:

[image]

When I try to navigate to

```
https://mywebsite.com/#/signup?utm_campaign=REMARKETING&utm_medium=cpi&utm_source=facebook
```

It doesn't trigger. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your utm parameters are all in URL's anchor. Notice # in your URL:

```
https://mywebsite.com/#/signup?utm_campaign=REMARKETING&utm_medium=cpi&utm_source=facebook
```

Therefore they are not recognised. You will need to place them before the anchor like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/?utm_campaign=REMARKETING&utm_medium=cpi&utm_source=facebook#/signup
```

There is already a thread on google forum about this issue [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/tag-manager/v7U7L0MEqQ0/JcG6YEO9AAAJ).

Comment: I used the # because we are using Angular. It worked after I remove the # . Now I should find a workaround.